# installing software with BASH

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

I'm new to CLI/BASH and I've got used to the basic commands.  I now want to get used to installing software on a server, such as nodejs, git etc.

Is there an software or a way I can practice BASH commands such as installing on a server without actually installing?  I want to improve my skills.  Is there a dummy server software or something like that?

Comment: Some package management tools have a test mode (e.g. `rpm --test`). If you want to play with bash, without breaking your system, the best thing to do these days is fire up the cheapest virtual machine from [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/), [Vultr](https://www.vultr.com/), [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) etc. Just remember to stop it when you're done. If you break it, just trash it and start again. They're only $5 a month, or less.

Comment: Do i have to install a package management tool? lol

Comment: Get interested in [docker](https://www.docker.com/). It is a great tool for "testing" things.

Comment: They will have one installed, `yum` for RedHat/CentOS etc., `apt` for Ubuntu etc.

Comment: Thanks i'll get an AWS virtual server and play around.  Is there a BASH command to "trash and start again"?

Comment: Write your script to take the install location as a (command line or configuration) parameter, and test with that destination set to `$HOME/tmp/test-installation` or something similar so that you run trial installs in non-sensitive places.  Only when you're confident that it is working do you think about using it to install in 'official' system locations.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should look into virtualising a machine. Then you can install whatever software you want.

www.virtualbox.org
or www.vmware.com

Either that or you can always uninstall stuff after using it apt:

```
 apt-get --purge remove <package>
 apt-get autoremove --purge
```

(That will remove all the package and all dependencies)

I don't think there is a 'dummy server' though ;) Virtual machines are definitely your friend here though.